# StoreKit2 equivalent to SKPaymentQueue.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, storekit

I'm using [StoreKit2](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10114) in a new iOS app to handle in-app subscription purchases. I'd like to support redemption of [Offer Codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_offer_codes_in_your_app) in the app, but I'm not seeing how to do that with StoreKit2.

Is there a StoreKit2 equivalent to original StoreKit's [SKPaymentQueue.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/3566726-presentcoderedemptionsheet)?

I'm not seeing anything in the docs that appears to handle Offer Codes specifically.
While there is this:

```
static func promotionalOffer(offerID: String, keyID: String, nonce: UUID, signature: Data, timestamp: Int) -> Product.PurchaseOption
```

my understanding is that Promotional offers are a separate thing to Offer codes.

Appreciate any pointers anyone has on how to allow in-app redemption of an Offer Code using StoreKit2. I'm assuming I should not include original StoreKit as well as StoreKit2 and call the older API, right?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @retendo - update posted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATED: there's a method now available in iOS 16 for this purpose (thanks to @Mamouneyya for spotting this):

[`presentOfferCodeRedeemSheet(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3954431-presentoffercoderedeemsheet)

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I asked this question during an Apple Developer event earlier this year (Optimize Subscriptions for Success: Acquisition on March 22 2022) and was told:

- There is no StoreKit2 equivalent (at least there wasn't as of March 2022)
- We should just use `SKPaymentQueue.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()` from the original StoreKit

That answer seems to imply it's fine to link against both StoreKit and StoreKit2 in the same app. I haven't yet tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is no longer true. It looks like Apple has indeed introduced a more modern API recently in iOS 16:
[`presentOfferCodeRedeemSheet(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3954431-presentoffercoderedeemsheet)

Comment: Thanks @Mamouneyya - I've updated the previous answer with this information